# Shellcode Segfault mid execution?

Tags: shellcode

In doing a university assignment, we are launching a shell on a remote server. That's all fine, I have connect back shell code, and when I hardcode the hex attack string into the server and jump to it, it launches. (The stack is executable, so that's not the issue (though it was for a while!))

However, when I pass it (packed using Perl) over the TCP connection, it only executes part of the way. Using gdb, I was able to determine that it set up the socket and connection, but segfaulted at the point it was pushing "/bin/sh" to the stack, specifically, on hitting a \x89 (mov ebx, esp).

Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working, can you comment the other question with what the problem was? Also - this is where you realise that you pretty much have to write your own shellcode, I've never had any luck with out-of-the-box shellcode, it's *always* really architecture specific and will usually segfault in my experience.

Comment: The previous one was an error on the part of the prof. The stack wasn't executable after all (although it was supposed to be)!

I feel hours of fun are in my imminent future...

Comment: This seems like something better suited for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a security question, it's a low-level architecture one. But to get you started, I'd suggest looking in to what a [Segmentation Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) actually represents.

Specifically, it happens on an attempt to read or write on a memory address to which the process does not access. The act of copying one register to another does not access memory, so it shouldn't be capable of triggering a segfault. Make sure you're actually performing the operation you think you are. Make sure that the issue isn't actually the *previous* or *next* instruction. Finally, another option is look at the location in memory of the EIP. It's probably not the problem, but it may be worth checking what memory is accessed as a side-effect of what's going on.